# Why doesn't this AppBar widget work? (LateInitialization Error, Null check on null value)

Tags: flutter

I am trying to refactor some repeated code to make it easier to update. The first obvious candidate is my project's repeated use of the scaffold appBar property, which is identical (or nearly so) in two dozen locations. So, I'd like to turn the appBar into a widget where I can just write `appBar: FbAppBar(title: 'Fonts'),` instead of 5 or 6 lines of code in 24 different files.

Here was my first attempt:

```
class FbAppBar extends StatelessWidget implements PreferredSizeWidget {
  FbAppBar({
    required String title,
    super.key,
  });

  late String title;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return AppBar(
      systemOverlayStyle: SystemUiOverlayStyle.dark,
      foregroundColor: Colors.grey[800],
      backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
      elevation: 0,
      title: Text(
        title.hardcoded,
        style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.titleLarge,
      ),
      actions: [],
    );
  }

  @override
  Size get preferredSize => Size.fromHeight(kToolbarHeight);
}
```

This ^^ got me a "LateInitializationError" on the title variable. So, I revised it to this:

```
class FbAppBar extends StatelessWidget implements PreferredSizeWidget {
  FbAppBar({
    required String title,
    super.key,
  });

  String? title;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return AppBar(
      systemOverlayStyle: SystemUiOverlayStyle.dark,
      foregroundColor: Colors.grey[800],
      backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
      elevation: 0,
      title: Text(
        title!.hardcoded,
        style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.titleLarge,
      ),
      actions: [],
    );
  }

  @override
  Size get preferredSize => Size.fromHeight(kToolbarHeight);
}
```

This ^^ got me a "Null check used on a null value" error.

Clearly I'm missing something (hopefully simple). The title won't be null (in practice) since I'm passing a string from the calling code (i.e. `appBar: FbAppBar(title: 'Fonts'),`), but I don't understand why that isn't working here.

Comment: It should be like `required this.title` in order to assign it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing assignment part (i.e. `this`) to assign the `title` property, so it should be like:

```
FbAppBar({
  required this.title,
  super.key,
});

final String title;
```

Comment: Doh! That was it. Thank you for reminding me I need to make an appointment with the eye doctor.

Answer (score 0):

Likely there's a point in your app state where the title property is null. Additionally, `String` doesn't have getter `hardcoded` unless you have a ***custom extension*** created for that.

You can change your `FbAppBar` to the one below.

```
class FbAppBar extends StatelessWidget implements PreferredSizeWidget {
  const FbAppBar({required this.title, super.key});

  final String? title;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return AppBar(
      systemOverlayStyle: SystemUiOverlayStyle.dark,
      foregroundColor: Colors.grey[800],
      backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
      elevation: 0,
      title: title != null
          ? Text(
              title!,
              style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.titleLarge,
            )
          : null,
      actions: [],
    );
  }

  @override
  Size get preferredSize => const Size.fromHeight(kToolbarHeight);
}
```